# List out all mounted devices?

Tags: android, usb

We have a usb port in our android tablet(version 4.0.3). When i was connecting the usb device to android tablet, the USB device is automatically mounted.

1) I wanted to list all the USB devices that are mounted.
 2) How to we unmounted this USB device through programmatically.

Thanks in advance.